# libegl-mesa0 package is broken and can't be upgraded/fixed because of "too-long line or missing newline" error

Tags: apt, dpkg

Here is the output of `sudo apt --fix-broken install`:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libegl-mesa0 libegl-mesa0:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libegl-mesa0 libegl-mesa0:i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/200 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6.144 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwayland-server0:i386' missing; as
suming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ghostscript-x' missing; assuming pac
kage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libudev1:amd64' missing; assuming pa
ckage has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gnupg' missing; assuming package has
 no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpam-systemd:amd64' missing; assum
ing package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 346295 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libegl-mesa0_21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.1_i386.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libegl-mesa0_21.2.6-0ubun
tu0.1~20.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/info/libegl-mesa0:i386.trigg
ers'
Preparing to unpack .../libegl-mesa0_21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libegl-mesa0:i386 (21.2.2-1ubuntu1pop0~1634226723~20.04~b715ae2~d
ev) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libegl-mesa0_21.2.6-0ubun
tu0.1~20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/info/libegl-mesa0:i386.trigg
ers'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libegl-mesa0_21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libegl-mesa0_21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am not too good with Linux, so I have failed to fix this issue in multiple ways. What should I do?

Comment: what happens if you do: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` ? Your question does not tell why you have broken packages, so what did you before you encountered this problem?

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu (Needed to clear some bloat anyway), but for future reference, both fail with the same error as `apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: Yes, that was to be expected. Still didn't tell us what you did **before** that problem occurred...

Comment: Are you using ubuntu with a pop ppa or POP OS?

Comment: Sorry for the time it took. From what I remember dpkg wasn't working because some .lists weren't working. Namely "libwayland-server0:i386", "ghostscript-x", "libudev1:amd64", "gnupg" and "libpam-systemd:amd64". I then deleted the lists to reinstall them but it just went down from there. The issue was resolved with me reinstalling my Ubuntu, but I hope this question can help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't resolve it,

Do this :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libegl-mesa0
```

It will install the packages and finally check if all the packages are up to date.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You will see all the packages are up to date!
The issue is resolved

Thanks !!!